# How to summarize all item detail totals at the foot of a report?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-reporting

I currently have a standard report that is working well and looks something like the following:

```
-----------------------------
Product: Foo
-----------------------------
Date      Itmes Sold    Total
Feb 01    5             14.95
Feb 03    2             5.98
Feb 04    10            29.90
-----------------------------
Total     17            50.83 [1]
-----------------------------

-----------------------------
Product: Bar
-----------------------------
Date      Itmes Sold    Total
Feb 01    7             34.94
Feb 03    1             4.99
-----------------------------
Total     8             39.92 [1]
-----------------------------

//...
more products
//....

-----------------------------
Report
Totals    26            90.75
-----------------------------
```

I've been asked to include a summary to the bottom of the report.  The summary will list the totals for each product (the information in [1]) similar to the following:

```
-----------------------------
Summary
-----------------------------
Foos      17            50.83
Bars       8            39.92
-----------------------------
Total     26            90.75
-----------------------------
```

As there is only one item detail per report, can this be done?  How would I create the summary?  Do I need to create a sub report?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a sub report just add a table after the product totals and bind a Summary object to the table using something like the [Object Data Source](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/objectdatasource.html). 
Use sub-reports lightly as they can quickly increase the processing time required to generate a Telerik report.